# C ++ Child class cannot inherit private member from Father class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, private

I am using Win8 VC++2012.

The code above is to show that child class B under NO circumstances can access the A::a. Neither can I change the access attribute of A::a but A::b and A::c.

So A::c is not inherited from A to B. But the sizeof(A) and sizeof(B) are 12 and 24 respectively, which means that A::a DO occupy memory in B.

1. How could B stores A::a in its memory while never could access it?
2. The book C++ Primer says, we can RESTORE the access attribute of base class member but can NOT change the it. Here my code shows that I can change access attributes of A::b from protected to public in B. Why?

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
private:
    int a;
protected:
    int b;
public:
    int c;

    A(int a, int b, int c): a(a), b(b), c(c)
    {
        cout << "A: ";
        cout << a << " ";
        cout << b << " ";
        cout << c << endl;
    }
};

class B: protected A
{
private:
    int d;
protected:
    int e;
    //using A::a; COMPILE ERROR
public:
    int f;
    //A::a;  COMPILE ERROR
    using A::c; //RESTORE A::c public access
    A::b; // change A::b from protected to public

    B(int d, int e, int f): A(d, e, f), d(d), e(e), f(f)
    {
        cout << "B\n";
        //cout << a << endl; COMPILE ERROR
        cout << b << " ";
        cout << c << " ";
        cout << d << " ";
        cout << e << " ";
        cout << f << endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    A a(1,2,3);
    B b(4,5,6);

    cout << "sizeof(A)=" << sizeof(A) << endl; //OUTPUT 12
    cout << "sizeof(B)=" << sizeof(B) << endl; //OUTPUT 24
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't trust `sizeof` to work as you expect.

Comment: Also, what do you expect? `private` is `private`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Children inherit parent's private members, but they can not access them. To access make them `protected`

```
class A
{
protected: // <<------------ make `a` as protected in parent
    int a;
```

Comment: As my code shows, private member A::a CANNOT be made protected in child class.

Comment: Look, I changed parent class, not child class.

Answer (score 1):

When you use inheritance you are creating an instance of the base class along with an instance of the derived class. All the members inside of the base class are constructed when you instantiate a derived class, even if they are not accessible to the derived class.

If you need the member to be private in the base class but you still would like to access it in the derived class. Create a protected accessor in the base class that will give you access to the private member.

```
 protected:    
 int &geta() { return a; }
```

Answer (score 1):

> So A::c is not inherited from A to B

did you mean

> So A::a is not inherited from A to B

But even then it is indeed inherited. It is just not directly accessible. However `B` will still have an `a`.

Why is this necessary? Because you can have **public methods in `A` that can set or get the value of `a`.** These functions can give B access to its own `a` indirectly.

For example

```
class A {
private:
    int a;      // a is private
public:
    void set_a(int i) {a = i;}
};

class B : protected A {
public:
    using A::set_a;   // we bring set_a to public access
};

int main() {
    B b;
    b.set_a(2);   // change b.a indirectly
    b.a = 2;      // Error
}
```

Comment: A::c is of course inherited from A to B. It is public member of A.

Comment: @Zachery You but that's what you wrote :)

Comment: @Zachery and inherited doesn't depend on visibility. **Everything is inherited from A**. The only thing different is the visibility level.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what the problem is:

B is an A, that's why there is some space occuped by the a attribute even if B can't access it.

If there was a public method geta() returning a, how could it return a if a wasn't in B ?